# Positionning a canvas and a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, how can I pack a canvas to the upper left corner and a button to the lower right corner? I tried with `can.pack(side=...)` and `button.pack(side=....)` but no luck. I want to get something like this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSjZQ.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.  You need to incorporate one more option: [`anchor`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/anchors.html).

Below is a simple script to demonstrate:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(bg="red", height=100, width=100)
canvas.pack(anchor=tk.NW)

button = tk.Button(text="button")
button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, anchor=tk.SE)

root.mainloop()
```

When you resize the window, notice how the canvas stays in the upper lefthand corner and the button stays in the lower righthand corner.